# How can I display text or graph in a Service, without an Activity?

Tags: android

I have a `Service` which with `BroadcastReceiver`, and want to display text when it gets some messages.

This `Service` is similar to TV remote control, so I don't want to use Notification or Toast. I want to show inputted digits in the right-top corner, just as the traditional TV.

[Network Meter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ckideas.networkmeter) can draw network speed graph in background, so this should be technically possible. However, I don't know how to start.

Any help is appreciable. Thank you!

Comment: Look into system alert windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using WindowManager.

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService("window");
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
params.format = PixelFormat.RGBA_8888;
params.flags = LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL 
                | LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                | LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE;
params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
params.x = 20;
params.y = 20;
params.width = 40;
params.height = 40;

wm.addView(yourView, params);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need. System alert windows are also good, but in my case TYPE_PHONE is more exact.